# I have a printer but it doesn't work on Linux

Tags: printing

So I have a Brother printer and I can print anything from Windows 10 or phone but on Ubuntu 20.04 it only prints: Blank pages or Black pages or Random characters like these: ☺♣1σ7τ♪V╨>ù6ù*√§+▌¶▲

I don't know what to do. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask ubuntu. Your question as it is currently formulated lacks any information for us to be able to help you. Which printer, what have you done, have you installed any drivers etc.

Comment: What is the model of printer?

Comment: How have you currently configured it?